# VBA - value conversion #REF! exception

Tags: vba, excel

It would be a problem that the designated area should be converted to value except where #REF! is error.

```
Sub keplet_helyett_ertek()
   Range("C3:J65").Select

   For Each akt_range In Selection.Areas
     If akt_range.Value <> CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
       akt_range.Formula = akt_range.Value
     End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Then, Run-time '13' error

[image]

Comment: `Selection.Areas` enumerates areas. `Value` of an Area is a 2D array. Apparently you wanted `Selection.Cells`. Then again, [you don't need `Selection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Answer (score 2):

Another problem is that if a cell dos NOT contain an error value you get the type mismatch too. The test to take is:

```
  For Each akt_range In Range("C3:J65")
     If Not IsError(akt_Range.Value) Then
       akt_range.Formula = akt_range.Value
     End If
   Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each akt_range In Selection.Areas
```

should be

```
For Each akt_range In Selection
```

To be more efficient replace

```
Range("C3:J65").Select
For Each akt_range In Selection.Areas
```

with

```
Dim akt_range As Range
For Each akt_range In Range("C3:J65")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub keplet_helyett_ertek()
Dim akt_range As Range, ok As Boolean
  Range("C3:J65").Select
  For Each akt_range In Selection
    ok = Not IsError(akt_range.Value)
    If Not ok Then ok = (akt_range.Value <> CVErr(xlErrRef))
    If ok Then akt_range.Formula = akt_range.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would argue that `ok` does not add to the readability or functionality of the code and should be removed.  `IsError` is clearly a boolean function and and the only other reason to set a flag is if the flag condition is needed outside of the original evaluation.  I recommend comparing @jkpieterse's answer side by side with yours and see which one is more readably.

Answer (score 0):

If, like the question states, you are only interested in excluding `#REF!` errors, ***this*** is the correct check:

```
  For Each akt_range In Range("C3:J65")
    If CStr(akt_range.Value2) <> CStr(CVErr(xlErrRef)) Then
      akt_range.Value = akt_range.Value2
    End If
  Next
```

Technically, the above will fail in the very special case of a formula returning the error code string for `#REF!` exactly, e.g., `="Error 2023"`. The ***absolutely bulletproof*** check is this:

```
  For Each akt_range In Range("C3:J65")
    If Not IsError(akt_range.Value2) Or CStr(akt_range.Value2) <> CStr(CVErr(xlErrRef)) Then
      akt_range.Value = akt_range.Value2
    End If
  Next
```

If you wish to exclude *all* errors, a better solution would be to use `.SpecialCells()` to eliminate the errors from the range before looping:

```
  For Each akt_range In Range("C3:J65").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlLogical + xlNumbers + xlTextValues)
    akt_range.Value = akt_range.Value2
  Next
```